# Public web API to get list of apps in App Store?

Tags: api, programming

I want to make an app, where user can find or mark apps that are similar. To do that first client need to able to browse app store content. If user set a keyword, i.e. "face", then I need list of app like Facebook an so on. Any of you know any such any such an API?

Comment: There are apps that track price changes in other apps, but I don't know if they're using a public API, or have just reverse-engineered whatever communications channel the App Store uses.

Comment: There is an affiliate API that maybe useful. But I gather the T&C's require you to be an affiliate as apposed to an app developer. https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---search-api.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of iOS and/or Android apps](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5311/list-of-ios-and-or-android-apps)

Answer (score 3):

There is an unofficial API for the Google Play Android Market: **[android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)**

> - You can browse market with any carrier or locale you want.
> - Search for apps using keywords or package name.
> - Retrieve an app info using an app ID.
> - Retrieve comments using an app ID.
> - Get PNG screenshots and icon

Command line usage:

```
java -jar androidmarketapi-X.Y.jar myemail mypassword myquery
```

[My source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10273254). Check out the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10272155), too.

Answer (score 0):

**[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/)** is:

> an <s>installable</s> catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform.

The entire catalog is available as one XML file:

```
https://f-droid.org/repo/index.xml
```

Here is a sample entry for one app:

```
       <application id="com.ichi2.anki">
      <id>com.ichi2.anki</id>
      <added>2010-11-12</added>
      <lastupdated>2015-04-21</lastupdated>
      <name>AnkiDroid</name>
      <summary>A flashcard-based study aid</summary>
      <icon>com.ichi2.anki.20403300.png</icon>
      <desc>&lt;p&gt;Anki is a program which makes remembering things easy. Because it is a lot more efficient than traditional study methods, you can either greatly decrease your time spent studying, or greatly increase the amount you learn. AnkiDroid is the Android port of Anki, and is compatible with Anki data.&lt;/p&gt;</desc>
      <license>GPLv3</license>
      <categories>Science &amp; Education</categories>
      <category>Science &amp; Education</category>
      <web>https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/wiki/Index</web>
      <source>https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android</source>
      <tracker>https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues</tracker>
      <marketversion>2.4.3</marketversion>
      <marketvercode>20403300</marketvercode>
      <package>
         <version>2.4.3</version>
         <versioncode>20403300</versioncode>
         <apkname>com.ichi2.anki_20403300.apk</apkname>
         <srcname>com.ichi2.anki_20403300_src.tar.gz</srcname>
         <hash type="sha256">25519608cf93ecf0a9a3dc20d9251e400b30fa99b5034ad2580cd3d58a522243</hash>
         <sig>9899acf97dcacd57c1a3fd134be93a77</sig>
         <size>6781118</size>
         <sdkver>7</sdkver>
         <added>2015-04-21</added>
         <permissions>ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,RECORD_AUDIO,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,VIBRATE,INTERNET,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE</permissions>
         <features>android.hardware.touchscreen,android.hardware.microphone</features>
      </package>
      <package>
         <version>2.4.2</version>
         <versioncode>20402300</versioncode>
         <apkname>com.ichi2.anki_20402300.apk</apkname>
         <srcname>com.ichi2.anki_20402300_src.tar.gz</srcname>
         <hash type="sha256">4e74743f0812da7ad23fb7cce541f689e567d8a514e7b8fd40b8c7ea6db7c073</hash>
         <sig>9899acf97dcacd57c1a3fd134be93a77</sig>
         <size>6743947</size>
         <sdkver>7</sdkver>
         <added>2015-04-04</added>
         <permissions>ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,RECORD_AUDIO,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,VIBRATE,INTERNET,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE</permissions>
         <features>android.hardware.touchscreen,android.hardware.microphone</features>
      </package>
      <package>
         <version>2.3.2</version>
         <versioncode>20302300</versioncode>
         <apkname>com.ichi2.anki_20302300.apk</apkname>
         <srcname>com.ichi2.anki_20302300_src.tar.gz</srcname>
         <hash type="sha256">5b2e3c0ac5eaf3f40f8353897d12f9ca0f38a1e1a677731286026d513a558143</hash>
         <sig>9899acf97dcacd57c1a3fd134be93a77</sig>
         <size>6471632</size>
         <sdkver>7</sdkver>
         <added>2014-11-11</added>
         <permissions>ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,RECORD_AUDIO,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,VIBRATE,INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE</permissions>
         <features>android.hardware.touchscreen,android.hardware.microphone</features>
      </package>
   </application>
```