# List of iOS and/or Android apps

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking for as large as possible list of app names. The app names can be iOS or Android, does not really matter.

The data is needed for a machine learning solution that requires large number of training examples. I can harvest manually a couple of hundreds but that is not enough.

Spent some time searching on the web and could not find any. Perhaps this information is classified but I wonder why.

Comment: classified? iOS is a walled-garden that denies web access....so web searching most likely is not going to help.

Comment: I put 2 answers here that may be of interest: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4638/1511

Answer (score 6):

F-Droid is a repository of Android apps.
All data is open source and freely reusable, including app names.

The app names can be extracted from the XML file https://f-droid.org/repo/index.xml by filtering on `<name>` tags.

I just extracted them for you, there are currently 1539 app names, here they are:
https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/b20677ebcf6a39ca3ba2

[image: F-Droid]

Answer (score 4):

There is one public access MySQL Database that hosts a large number of records about iOS apps: [StatsiOS](http://blog.statsios.com/post/70995857813/sql-queries-to-appstore)

After little of cleaning I could obtain 1.98M unique app names!

Answer (score 2):

There are available Databases and Crawlers for both Android and iOS app stores

**[Google Play Apps Crawler](https://github.com/MarcelloLins/GooglePlayAppsCrawler)**

> The main idea of this project is to gather/mine data about apps of the Google Play Store and build a rich database so that developers, android fans and anyone else can use to generate statistics about the current play store situation

**[Apple Store Apps Crawler](https://github.com/MarcelloLins/Apple-Store-Crawler)**

> A simple, scalable scrapper for apps data being listed on Apple's AppStore